# Can singular value decomposition be applied to a matrix of $n\times 1$ size?

Tags: svd, matrix-decomposition

Can singular value decomposition be applied to a matrix of $n \times 1$ size (a vector)?

Usually I see that matrix is of size of $n \times m$.

Any example?

Comment: I think everyone wants to know...why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVD (singular value decomposition) can be applied to an n by m matrix, as long as n and m are both positive integers.  n = 1 and/or m = 1 are perfectly fine.

Let M be an n by m matrix.  Then the SVD of M is U,S,V such that $M = U S V^H$, with U being n by n unitary, S being n by m, V being m by m unitary.

Example.  Let M be the 2 by 1 vector $[2, 1]^T$. Then its SVD is: U is a 2 by 2 matrix with rows [0.447213595499958, -0.894427190999916] and [0.894427190999916;  0.447213595499958], S is $[2.236067977499790; 0]^T$, and V is the 1 by 1 "matrix" 1.

Comment: Do you really need 15 digits precision in your Example?

Comment: No, but I had it set to long format, so it saved me time by not changing format and changing back. But now that I've typed this comment, it cost me time on net.

Comment: A Pythagorean triple like `M = [3, 4]` would be a nicer choice...:)